# How to display two elements <h> and <p> next to each other without alignment glitch?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a CV using HTML & CSS as my first little project.

I'm having an issue getting the some very basic alignment sorted but I can't (for the life of me) work out why this slight displacement is happening. What am I miss guys?

The displacement is how the UL division sits next to the H3 division of 'skills'

Some direction and advise would be great! Thanks, and I hope I've formatted this post correctly.

[image]

```css
html {
  margin: 48px 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "calibri";
  max-width: 980px;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
}

.name {
  line-height: 1em;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.contact p {
  font-weight: 250;
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
}

.contact strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.header {
  width: 175px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.skills {
  width: 475px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
  display: inline-block;
}

.skills ul {
  columns: 2;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.experience {
  width: 475px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">

  <h1>Name</h1>

</div>

<div class="contact">

  <p><strong>Email</strong>: blabla@gmail.com<br><strong>No</strong>: 0000 000 000</p>

</div>

<!-- Bio section -->

<div class="bio">

  <p>I am a creative, determined and hardworking individual looking to secure a full-time position in a role that promotes development and growth. I love engaging with projects and working to a high standard, I have been effective in previous media related
    roles in tasks such as content creation and article publication.</p>

</div>

<!-- Skills -->

<h3 class="header">skills</h3>

<div class="skills">


  <ul>
    <li>Content Creation</li>
    <li>Social Media</li>
    <li>Document Publication</li>
    <li>Document Editing</li>
    <li>HTML/CSS</li>
    <li>Customer Service</li>
    <li>Blog Writing</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<!-- Experience -->

<h3 class="header">Experience</h3>

<!-- VANEL -->

<div class="experience">

  <h4>Communication, Digital Media and Youth Development Internship</h4>
  <p>VANEL (Voluntary Action North East Lincolnshire)</p>
  <p>VANEL are an independent organisation that support the development, infrastructure and expansion of non-profits in the local area.</p>

  <div class="experience-list">

    <ul>

      <li>Created and circulated editorial work for the local third-sector industry in Lincolnshire.</li>
      <li>Developed a local marketing and social media plan for a community welfare campaign.</li>
      <li>Worked directly with younger people to strengthen their relationship with the third-sector.</li>
      <li>Lead a video project with a group of students from a local college, I liaised with tutors and small charity owners, bringing the two together.</li>
      <li>Social critique and development of an area suffering from a lack of youth support.</li>

    </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: WHat is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is the UL element to sit next to the Skills header element on the same level, not displaced. 

Here is a screenshot! https://imgur.com/hR6XRBF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the `div` and `h3` in a wrapper div:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:nowrap;">
   <h3 class="header">skills</h3>

  <div class="skills">
   <ul>
    <li>Content Creation</li>
    <li>Social Media</li>
    <li>Document Publication</li>
    <li>Document Editing</li>
    <li>HTML/CSS</li>
    <li>Customer Service</li>
    <li>Blog Writing</li>
   </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've been at work so I can't put this into practise yet but I will do tomorrow morning. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following on your header class:

```
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0;
```

This is because the default value of **vertical-align** is **baseline** for *inline-block* elements

```css
html {
  margin: 48px 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "calibri";
  max-width: 980px;
}
img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
}
.name {
  line-height: 1em;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.contact p {
  font-weight: 250;
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
}
.contact strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.header {
  width: 175px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.skills {
  width: 475px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
  display: inline-block;
}
.skills ul {
  columns: 2;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
.experience {
  width: 475px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <h1>Name</h1>
</div>
<div class="contact">
  <p><strong>Email</strong>: blabla@gmail.com<br><strong>No</strong>: 0000 000 000</p>
</div>
<!-- Bio section -->
<div class="bio">
  <p>I am a creative, determined and hardworking individual looking to secure a full-time position in a role that promotes development and growth. I love engaging with projects and working to a high standard, I have been effective in previous media related roles in tasks such as content creation and article publication.</p>
</div>
<!-- Skills -->
<h3 class="header">skills</h3>
<div class="skills">
  <ul>
    <li>Content Creation</li>
    <li>Social Media</li>
    <li>Document Publication</li>
    <li>Document Editing</li>
    <li>HTML/CSS</li>
    <li>Customer Service</li>
    <li>Blog Writing</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the information! I've been at work so I can't put this into practise yet but I will do tomorrow morning. Thanks in advance! Answers like this do wonders.

Comment: No worries bud. Always happy to help!